# Cake php, sql error 150

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, web-applications

before I post my problem/code I will give a little backstory to what I am doing. Currently I am developing a website using cakephp and mysql. I have a login system which users can log into and each user can create a team. When a user creates a team, they are considered the team lead. There are two tables in my database. One is for users and the other one is for teams. In the teams table there is a field called user_id which represents the user who created the team. It is a foriegn key which links to a field called id in the User table.

So when a user creates a team, I want my program to automatically recognize the id of the leader and save it as the user_id in the team model which goes into my table.

Here is my code in the team Model class

```
<?php
class TeamsController extends AppController {

public $name = 'Teams';

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                    //THIS LINE SETS THE TEAM LEAD
        $this->Team->set('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));

        echo $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Team->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Team->set('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('The team  has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The team could not be created. Please, try again.');
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I am grabbing the user_id from the current user model and putting it into the team model.

However, When I do this i keep getting a mysql error 150, which has something to do with the foriegn key constraints. I am not sure why this is happening. I checked and cross referenced all the data from both tables, and the data is in both tables! Both tables are Innodb and the both of the fields are ints and do not take nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like:

Your controller's code:

```
<?php
class TeamsController extends AppController {

public $name = 'Teams';

public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $team_details = $this->request->data;
    $team_details['Team']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($this->Team->save($team_details)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The team  has been saved');
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The team could not be created. Please, try again.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We should not take a user_id in hidden_field,Because we have it already in Auth.and also security reason.

Comment: What is the difference between the set method and the method you used above?

Comment: I followed the above method to use the saved record array for future purpose also. You might not be able to access the user_id with that field if it is different than current logged in user_id. set() method will work if you are not providing any array to the save() method. Check this link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-set-one-two-null

Comment: Hey without starting a new question, how would I change a field in the user model through the team model?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   class TeamsController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Teams';

   public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                //THIS LINE SETS THE TEAM LEAD
    $this->request->data['Team']['user_id']= $this->Auth->user('id');


    if ($this->Team->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->set('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
        $this->Session->setFlash('The team  has been saved');
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The team could not be created. Please, try again.');
    }

   }
}
```